# How do I enable automatic email updates once a List is updated?

Tags: custom-list, tasks

I am using SharePoint 2013. What must the SharePoint admin do to make sure team members get updates once an edit has been executed to a List?

Answer (score 2):

- Create a new alert.
- Choose users that belong to your team in "Send Alerts To".
- Choose the option "Existing items are modified" in "change type"

Picture:

[image]

Comment: I do not see any alert within the blue ribbon in this list. Perhaps the SharePoint Admin did not enable it yet.

Comment: Could you paste an image of your ribbon?

Comment: I took a screen shot. However, I can't see where to add a screenshot in the Add Comment section.

Comment: You can edit your question and add on this place.